# Email issue, sending some lines of string but not sending others

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have created the following code:

```
for (i=0;i<count;i++) {
    substM=LinesList.get(index[i]).split("[|]"); 
    ///*********Email settings************////
    final String username = "it-support@test.com";
    final String password = "IamSoHappy";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.test.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
              protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
          }
    });
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("it-support@test.com"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
    InternetAddress.parse("Alen@test.com"));
    message.setSubject(substM[10]+" is left open by "+ substM[11]);

    ///*******To get Date and Time******/////
    String st=substM[13];
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss",Locale.getDefault()).parse(st);
    ///******************************//////
    String st1= substM[10],st2=substM[11];
    message.setText("Dear IT Support Team,"
               + "\n\n"+st1+" is left opened by '"+ st2+"' since "+date +" .. !!"
               + "\n\n"+"Regards," + "\nIT Support Team");
    Transport.send(message);
}
```

If `index[i]` contains the index in string list that contains the lines which I want to view, and these lines contains following info :

```
002|0000|00|00002392651|41933.3385069444|00032018|M|        |1|2|OFFICE 2|guest03 guest03|0|141021080727| 
002|0000|00|00002392651|41932.3409953704|00032018|M|        |1|2|OFFICE 2|Lubna|0|141020081102|
002|0000|00|00002392651|41933.3385069444|00032018|M|        |1|2|OFFICE 2|guest03 guest03|0|141021080100|
```

I was able to print all `lineslist.get(index[i])`, and its output, the same as the above lines, I am also able to receive first and last line but, not the middle one ?

Why is that ???

Comment: Are you sure it's being sent?  What does the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?  Are you sure it's not in your spam mailbox?

Comment: yes its being sent, and its not in the spam.. Can i ask how to view debugging results in Eclipse ?

Comment: If i do changes or deletions for the first and the last line, the email will not be sent for both as well, its really strange ????

Comment: I don't know how to debug it in Eclipse.  If you can't figure out how to view the console output in Eclipse, you can use the Session.setDebugOut method to redirect the debug output to a file.